# Getting started with backbone

Tags: backbone.js

Amateurish this question might be but none the less could use a hand. Just got backbone out of the packaging and started the hello world example but cant seem to get it up and running. Any chance someone could tell me why Im not seeing the results of this?

```
(function($){

var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $(body), //attaches this.el to an existing element

    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this, 'render'); //fixes loss of context for this within elements
        this.render(); //not all views are self-rendering. This is one.
    },

    render: function(){
        $(this.el).html("<ul><li>Hello World!</li></ul>");
    }
});
var listVew = new ListView();


})(jQuery);
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> Hello Backbone </title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.1.6/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>

<script src="backbone.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should be able to set your `el` to the `body` just by using `el: 'body',`. You don't need to wrap it in a jQuery object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I tried your code in a jsfiddle and got this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: body is not defined`

  - use the string `'body'` as your view's `el` selector

This works: http://jsfiddle.net/PeGW6/

Also note you are using a very very old version of backbone. Upgrade to the most recent build.

Comment: Tried everything you mentioned but to no avail unfortunately. I dont believe but may very well be wrong that it isnt an issue with the code firing. Throwing some alerts into the first bit of the code inside of the anonymous function they react. Also the matter of html() clearing out the script calls is not the root of the issue as I initially begin using append.

Comment: So in your `render` put `console.log("render:", this.el, this.$el)` and that will confirm if the document is ready yet or not. if `this.$el` is `[]`, you'll know that's the issue. If you post your code into a jsfiddle, we can help you debug there.

Comment: Alright so some progress was made. Figured out a chunk of the issue was being cause by my forgetfulness in not putting quotes around body in el: $(body). When I post my code into jsfiddle it not works perfectly but for whatever reason off of my own computer Im not seeing the text in body being updated. I tried alerting this.el and this.$el however it outputted nothing. Kindof confused though about why it would work on jsfiddle but not my comp

Comment: Sorry nevermind on the part regarding the console.log the response is -- "render: 
[prevObject: e.fn.e.init[1], context: #document, selector: "body"]
 undefined" when viewed from my computer and alternatively "render: 
[<body>, context: #document, selector: "body"]
 undefined" from jsfiddle

Comment: I think the main problem was missing quotes around `'body'`. Next, update to modern backbone. If you are still having trouble, reproduce it in a jsfiddle. I have no magic ball that will tell me about problems that only happen on your computer without you so much as copy/pasting the error message into a question here.

Comment: Sure thing you were quite helpful so far so figured id give it a shot haha thanks for the hand!